# Scalar extensions and bi-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I know that given a ring morphism $f: A\to B$ and an A-module $M$. One can define a structure of B-module over $M \otimes_A B$. At the same time $M \otimes_AB$ still is an A module.

1. Is the term "extension" a bit misleading? Sure, this construction is canonical and the obvious one to make M a B module. However we don't even know if the natural map $i: M \to M \otimes_AB \; m \to m \otimes1$ is injective. Can we say something about the structure of $M \otimes_A B$ resembling M? [Who are his submodule, What properties can we extend etc...].
2. Every time i find that a certain module is a module on two different ring A and B i am confused. Are there properties that M has from both structure? It seems to me that they can be very different objects. However Sometimes, given $\mathfrak{m} $ maximal in A, when considering the A module $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ one studies it as $A/\mathfrak{m}$ vector space and deduces properties for the A-module, but this works because because the scalar moltiplication works exactly the same. Are there other cases that work the same? In this particular case of $M \otimes_AB$ what can we say?

Thanks

Comment: Is $M$ an $A$-bimodule? Are you assuming anything about your rings (e.g. commutative, unital)? These are important assumptions to state in your question, since without certain assumptions certain constructions, like tensor products, don't make sense.

Comment: @Exitpath Possibly the user is using $B$ as an $(A, A)$ bimodule, so that the $A$ module structure on the tensor product is on the right.

Comment: I think as written the question has too many parts, and some of those parts are pretty unclear at this point. Perhaps it should change into two questions: 1) What can one say about the structure of the extension based on the structure of $M$ and 2) the thing about change-of-rings.   They are independent of each other.  Asking something like "is X misleading" is pretty subjective and not really a good fit for the site.